# Run iTunes without virtualizing Windows?

Tags: wine, itunes

I know I could use VirtualBox or VMWare, but does anyone know of a way to run iTunes without having to run Windows virtually on Ubuntu?

Will iTunes run using Wine?  Is there a better more native way to run iTunes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[iTunes on Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347) is the closest thing to "native" you'll get but it's not supported very well and you won't get device syncing.

iTunes through VirtualBox is probably going to give you the highest quality experience.. You'll probably be able to use devices (read: iPods, iPhones, [iRacks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rw2nkoGLhrE), etc) as you would with a real Windows install. It's just heavy.

I do wonder why you want to run iTunes. If it's just for purchasing, playing and syncing audio files, there are alternatives (Rhythmbox, Banshee, Amarok, MPD+Frontends, etc) that are arguably better and are truly native applications. They just take a little getting used to.

Comment: No.. I actually hate iTunes, but if you buy an Apple product you pretty much have to run it.  You can't do a single thing with a brand new iPad without iTunes.  So just wondering. Basically the answer is you have to run Windows (or have a mac) (Virtually or otherwise)

Comment: Indeed. Thankfully VBox's USB support is pretty decent once you get it working.

Comment: I'd be careful updating firmware on the iPhone through VBox. I did that a while back and it failed, bricking the phone. I had to redo it from a Windows box.

Comment: My iPad wouldn't run with iTunes on wine. I had to install Vbox with Windows and iTunes to have music on my tablet.

Answer (score 3):

Use Banshee to import all meta data from itunes!

In Banshee, Import > Itunes library > navigate to the itunes file - and voa la!

This made my switch from itunes to ubuntu a cinch.

Comment: Hey that's magnificent!

Answer (score 1):

You can use itunes with either wine or PlayonLinux. PlayonLinux is best as performance wise. For installation instruction  see 
http://freshtutorial.com/install-itunes-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, everything I've read says this isn't possible. Your best bet is still a virtual machine or use Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 0):

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347

As the answer is to any question about Wine, kind of.

You could try, say, Songbird or something. Not really a satisfactory replacement for me, but, it's something.

Meh, I had a hard time finding the right media player for Windows. I won't even try on Ubuntu.

Comment: op's comments seem to indicate it's for Apple Hardware Device support.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04 should allow you to sync and manage your iPod or iPhone with Rhythmbox.