# How can I stream music from a Mac to Ubuntu?

Tags: itunes

I have a Mac with all of my music on it in Itunes. Itunes has a feature called "Home Sharing" which allows someone to stream the content from one computer to another. Is there a way to set this feature up in Ubuntu?

Comment: For "Home Sharing" you need iTunes installed on all the computers involved. Related question: [What is the best way to run iTunes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2728/what-is-the-best-way-to-run-itunes).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to switch on DAAP network sharing in Rythembox by going to the Edit > Plugins and checking the box next to DAAP. You can also use the configure button to share your Ubuntu music to itunes:

[image]

Comment: Does this work with the latest iTunes? [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=187145) made me ask.

Comment: Nope, that won't work, recent versions of itunes have encrypted daap.

Comment: Need to do it the other way, stream from the Mac to Ubuntu

Comment: Encrypted? What the fish!? Junk iTunes and replace it with proper music player on the mac.