# Repair a corrupted iPod shuffle

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, music, banshee, ipod

I have a iPod shuffle 4th Generation 2GB. I wanted to format it and I run this command:

```
rm -rf /media/IPOD/* /media/IPOD/.*
```

that removed anything from it.

Then I ejected my iPod from the computer, and inserted it again.

I tried Amarok, Gtkpod and Noise to reinitialize it...

Noise ouputs this in terminal:

```
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 20:02:48.209188] iPodDevice.vala:62: Error parsing db at file:///media/IPOD: Couldn't find an iPod database on /media/IPOD.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 20:02:48.209274] Music will not function properly.
```

while Amarok says `"iPod was not initialized: failed to initialize the iPod"` outputting this in the terminal:

```
QDir::mkdir: Empty or null file name(s)
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 20 (X_GetProperty)
  Resource id:  0x3400192
```

---

I don't care if I lose any iPod songs (what songs if I formated it?). I want to repair it and to use it under Ubuntu.

How can I do this?

---

When I start my iPod I hear a voice in the headphones: "Please use iTunes to sync music with this iPod."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I installed the latest release of Amarok (2.8) and I started it.

I inserted my iPod in the computer and I mounted it. A popup window from Amarok appeared and I clicked <kbd>Initialize</kbd> button.

It didn't output any error.

To copy music in my iPod I used Banshee (`sudo apt-get install banshee`). After that I heard the same message in my iPod: "Please use iTunes to sync music with this iPod.".

I installed Gtkpod (`sudo apt-get install gtkpod`) and I inserted and mounted my iPod. It appeared in the Gtkpod application.

I clicked `Normalize` item from the right click menu. I saved the settings and I ejected the iPod from the computer.

Result? My iPod works fine again!

Answer (score 3):

You can use it under Ubuntu but fixing it will probably require a system where you can use iTunes. From an Ubuntu point of view that would be Wine with iTunes installed in it as shown here [Run iTunes without virtualizing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2728/what-is-the-best-way-to-run-itunes). Since iTunes will (re)create your database but software from other operating system are more than likely only able to use the device.

Another option would be to get a hold of a Mac, run iTunes and have it fixed and then go back to Ubuntu to store music.